# How to execute function in find or to save the data in variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to execute function after I use find() from mongodb database.

```
    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  Game.find({'homeTeamName': req.body.homeTeamName})
    .then(games => res.json(games))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json('no games')
    )
})
```

Is it possible to execute function in .then or just to save somewhere  games . 
And I have one more question, can I do something like this to find all away games too ?

```
Game.find({'homeTeamName': req.body.homeTeamName} || {'awayTeamName': req.body.homeTeamName})
```

Comment: Yes, you can call a function there and yes there is a possibility to query based on multiple conditions but not like this.

Comment: use `$or` condition like this `Game.find({
  $or:[{ 'homeTeamName': req.body.homeTeamName }, { 'awayTeamName': req.body.homeTeamName }]
})`

Comment: please give me an example how to call a function there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this,

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
 Game.find({$or:[{ "homeTeamName": req.body.homeTeamName }, { "awayTeamName": req.body.homeTeamName }]})
  .then((games) => {
       executeYourFunction();
       res.json(games)
   })
  .catch(err =>
    res.status(404).json('no games')
   )
})
executeYourFunction(){
  console.log("success")
}
```